# Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it

Tags: android, kotlin

File Crime.kt

```
@Entity
data class Crime (@PrimaryKey val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
                  var title: String = "",
                  var date: Date = Date(),
                  var isSolved: Boolean = false)
```

File CrimeTypeConverters.kt

```
class CrimeTypeConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromDate(date: Date?): Long?{
        return date?.time
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toDate(millisSinceEpoch: Long?): Date? {
        return millisSinceEpoch?.let {
            Date(it)
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toUUID(uuid: String?): UUID? {
        return UUID.fromString(uuid)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromUUID(uuid: UUID?): String? {
        return uuid?.toString()
    }
}
```

error :
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
private java.util.Date date;
C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\CriminalIntentv2\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\bignerdranch\android\criminalintent\database\CrimeDatabase.java:8: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class CrimeDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
^[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (NON_INCREMENTAL).

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

Comment: Where do you have your `@TypeConverters` annotation to point Room to your `@TypeConverter`?

Comment: BTW, UUID as id is usually a bad practice, if you just want convenience: @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the converters with your database

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        Crime::class, ...
    ]
)
@TypeConverters(
    //...
    CrimeTypeConverters::class
)
abstract class CrimeDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
   //...
}
```

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters), there is a way to use it on entity case by case, but I can't find a reference now.

I think the keywords that tells the problem are:

```
...Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. ...\CrimeDatabase.java:8: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor...
```